# _background-variant.scss overrides background color

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a angular 8 application with bootstrap.

But there is a file: _background-variant.scss in bootstrap thar overrides my background color menu. And I dont want that.

```
.bg-dark {
    /* background-color: #343a40!important;
```

Because if I disable this in google chrome tools. The layout is in his original state.

But so my question is: How to disable this: bg-dark?

I tried to remove the file. or to comment the content of the file. But nothing changed.

So how to do this?

Thank you

this i have in angular.json:

```
 "styles": [
              "./node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.min.css",
              "./node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"

            ]
```

This is what I mean. If I disable this. Then everything looks fine.

[image]

Comment: If it is being overridden, you need to add your .css file after the bootstrap .css file in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about this question; are you using `.bg-dark` as your own CSS selector somewhere else? Bootstrap should not be setting background colors without being prompted to.

If you are using `.bg-dark` somewhere, you could try using something with more specificity.

Rather than just using `.bg-dark` as a selector, you could try either using an Id selector, or using a combined selector targeting the class and element

ex: `.bg-dark div`

Comment: yes, I have a .bg-dark  {
  background: #419fcb;
} in a theme-vital.css

Comment: In that case either just change your class name for your background or use higher specificity!